# Adding rows to DataGrid through XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

Is it possible to add one or more rows to WPF DataGrid through XAML, without binding it to a collection. What I'm looking for would essentially be something like:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
    ...
    </DataGrid.Columns>

    <DataGrid.Items>
        <DataGridRow>
        ...
        </DataGridRow>
    </DataGrid.Items>
</DataGrid>
```

I'm going to use it at design-time to see how my DataGrid columns would look like without actually running the code.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Feeling lucky. Found it myself. Here's the simplest way.

Create a dummy class with the same public properties (important that you define members as properties and not fields). For example:

```
public class Dummy
{
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public DateTime DueDateStart { get; set; }       
}
```

Import your project namespace into XAML by adding the following import at the top:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourProjectNamespace"
```

Now you can add items (rows) to your DataGrid at design-time like (make sure your columns have proper bindings):

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Subject" Binding="{Binding Path=Subject}"/>
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Body" Binding="{Binding Path=Body}"/>
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Due Date" Binding="{Binding Path=DueDateStart}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>

    <local:Dummy Subject="Subject 1" Body="Body 1" ... />
    <local:Dummy Subject="Subject 2" Body="Body 2" ... />
</DataGrid>
```

Hope this helps someone!

### Update

Since this is now a popular post, I thought I should update this with the **standard** way of doing things.

WPF supports a concept known as Design-Time Data that serves this exact purpose. A few key advantages of using Design-Time Data over the approach I mentioned above include:

1. Design-Time Data remains separate from application functionality.
2. You do not need to change anything at all to switch your controls between design and run modes.
3. Data lives in XML files that are easily editable.

Here are the steps to create design-time data files:

1. Open your project in Blend (comes free with VS2015 and VS2017).
2. Open your View (Window or Control that you're working with).
3. From Data tool window (docked with Solution Explorer by default), choose **Create Sample Data From Class**.
4. Select your VM class. You should choose the same class that your control will actually use at runtime as its `DataContext`.
5. Blend will create an XML file with sample data automatically filled in for you. The file will look something like this:

   ```
   <local:TestDataList xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourNamespaceHere" Capacity="46" ID="33" Name="Maecenas curabitur cras">
     <local:TestData ID="66" Name="Aenean vestibulum class"/>
     <local:TestData ID="34" Name="Duis adipiscing nunc praesent"/>
     <local:TestData ID="91" Name="Accumsan bibendum nam"/>
   </local:TestDataList>
   ```

**Important to note that you do not need Blend to generate this file. You can do this by hand too.**

6. Now in your DataGrid (or whatever control you're working with), add the following property (change file path according to your project):

   ```
   d:DataContext="{d:DesignData Source=SampleData/TestDataListSampleData.xaml}"
   ```
7. Given that your control has its properties properly set (e.g. `ItemsSource`, `Columns` etc.), sample data will start showing in the designer immediately.

Just for completion, note that Blend cannot generate automatic data for generic classes. For example, if your VM class contains a property of type `List<string>` (or if the VM class itself is a generic class), you'll not see that property getting generated in the sample data file. In that case, you must create your own dummy class inheriting from the generic class and then use it as the type of your property. For example:

```
public class MyListOfStrings : List<string>
{ }
```

Comment: This is not working for me. Did you do anything else apart from this. For me it is just showing the blank rows for each new local:dummy object.

Comment: @Balachandra: Make sure you're following the instructions exactly; e.g. your `Dummy` class must be `public`, plus the properties must be public properties, not fields. The solution has worked for me and several other people, so most probably u r missing something.

Comment: @Balachandra You get empty lines if the bindings for the properties in the DataGrid.Columns definitions are missing or incorrect. I've posted an answer with an example.

Comment: @dotNET If you would like, feel free to add the code from my example into your own answer and I'll delete mine since it's more of a clarification and not a complete answer in itself. I'd have posted it as a comment except the format doesn't exactly lend itself to long code snippets.

Comment: @Mr.B: You either put them inside DataGrid or you bind `ItemsSource`. You don't do both.

Comment: IMPORTANT: At first it didn't work but then I created a NEW `Class` file and then made the automatically created class under that class file public (and added some properties I needed in to the class). Then I had to ADD `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:namespace:YourNameSpaceHERE"` to my `DataGrid`'s definition, like this:

`<DataGrid xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourNameSpaceHERE"> ... </DataGrid>`