# Use model properties as source for a DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I need a `DataGrid` that will just have two rows that correspond to two properties in the model.

Is there a way to reference these objects?

Something like this:

```
        <DataGrid>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Foo" Binding="{Binding Foo}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>

            <!-- Is there a container I can load my objects into? -->
            <Something Content="{Binding Property1}"/>
            <Something Content="{Binding Property2}"/>
        </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Which type do the properties have, `string`? Why not expose a collection and bind it to `ItemSource`? What about the `ContentControls`, should they serve any purpose?

Comment: They are a custom class. Yes, if there's no easy way to specify the 2 elements I think i will put them into a list and set the list as ItemSource. It was just a try to be more explicit to say what is displayed in the datagrid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DataGrid` use its `ItemsSource` property to fill it's rows, it expect an `IEnumerable` so you have to create an `IEnumerable` of your properties.

Here is your model:

```
public class Model
{
    public Model()
    {
        Property1 = new BarModel();
        Property2 = new BarModel();
        Items = new[] {Property1, Property2};
    }

    public BarModel Property1 { get; }
    public BarModel Property2 { get; }
    public IReadOnlyList<BarModel> Items { get; }
}

public class BarModel
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
}
```

And here the xaml part:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource={Binding Items}>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Foo" Binding="{Binding Foo}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Edit:

You can also add items by [pure xaml code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18495961/361177) but then you will have to do a binding for each relevant property:

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Foo" Binding="{Binding Foo}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>

    <DataGrid.Items>
        <local:BarModel Foo="{Binding Property1.Foo}"/>
        <local:BarModel Foo="{Binding Property2.Foo}"/>
    </DataGrid.Items>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Ok, I think putting them into a list will be the easiest way.

Comment: @Klamsi, It's the expected way (for futurs reader of your code). What can be done is a model proxy that will automatically bind to all properties (`Foo` & co.), it's an interesting exercise but overkill and inefficient. Taking the question from another angle, do you really need to expose the two properties ? are they used ? doesn't the list is enough ? If you want to bind to a property from `ObjectInstanceProperty1`, you can also bind to it via `Items[0]`.